# PHP object references

Tags: php, object, reference

I am confused on how PHP handles objects and references. I know that objects are assigned or passed by reference when assigning to an variable or passing to a function. But however, the following example is confusing:

```
$node = new Node("a", 1);
$a = new Node("b", 2);
$b = new Node("c", 3);
$c = new Node("d", 4);
$d = new Node("e", 5);
$d->setPrevious($c);
$d->setNext(null);

$c->setNext($d);
$c->setPrevious($b);

$b->setNext($c);
$b->setPrevious($a);

$a->setNext($b);
$a->setPrevious($node);

$node->setNext($a);
$node->setPrevious(null);

echo countNode($node);
echo "\n";
remove($node->getNext());
echo countNode($node);
echo "\n";

function countNode(Node $node) {
    $i = 0;
    while (null !== $node) {
        $i++;
        $node = $node->getNext();
    }
    return $i;
}

function remove(Node $node) {
    $next = $node->getNext();
    $previous = $node->getPrevious();

    $previous->setNext($next);
    $next->setPrevious($previous);
}
```

where the output is as follows:

```
5
4
```

I understand that I do not need to return the node object from the "remove" method since the object is passed by reference. But what is about the "countNode" method? The `$node` variable has to be `null`, hasn't it?

**UPDATE**

Since the question seems to be ambigous, I would like to ask the question a little more precisely: The `remove` method changes the reference of `$node`. After removing a node from the doubly linked list, the size is decreased from 5 to 4.

But `countNode` is also reassigning the `$node` variable and has therefore to return 0?! Why is the reference not changed in `countNode`?

Comment: You remove the 'b' node, not the 'a' node. But even removing a node from the doubly linked list does not invalidate the variable the node was created in.

Comment: @Dormilich what I want to point out is that the `$node` variable is changed by the `remove` function in its size but not by the `countNode` method. Because `countNode` iterates over the doubly linked list, the second echo has to show 0?!

Answer (score 0):

`$node` doesn't to be NULL because In your function `remove` you did not set the `$node` to NULL. You should update your `remote` function by

```
function remove(Node $node) {
    $next = $node->getNext();
    $previous = $node->getPrevious();

    $previous->setNext($next);
    $next->setPrevious($previous);
    $node = null;
}
```

The reference of `$node` will not clean in memory, It alway exists before  `php` aplication closed or you set it to `NULL`

**Update**

```
function countNode(Node $node) {
    $i = 0;
    while (null !== $node) {
        $i++;
        $node = $node->getNext(); //This Line
    }
    return $i;
}
```

Your code in `countNode` changed the first node of your list to `NULL` because you update your `$node` variable when you do while loop. Then this line update your $note variable reference to NULL when while loop ended.

Readmore about Object An Reference:

https://www.toptal.com/php/objects-references-php-memory

Comment: I want to point out is that the `$node` variable is changed by the `remove` function in its size but not by the `countNode` method. Because `countNode` iterates over the doubly linked list, the second echo has to show 0?! Hasn't it?